# How to correctly pack Log data in Go

Tags: go-ethereum, events, abi, golang, logs

Using go-ethereum, I want to convert a struct containing my log fields into a types.Log{} object containing the data bytes and topics. Essentially, I want to do the opposite of the `Parse<EventName>` method that gets generated by `abigen`. So far I have the following simplified code to generate and validate the log data:

```
    myABI, err := mycontract.MyContractMetaData.GetAbi()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    event := myABI.Events["MyEventName"]
    inputs := event.Inputs
    packedData, err := inputs.Pack(myEvent.IndexedField, myEvent.NonIndexedField1, ...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    _, err = inputs.Unpack(packedData)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

However, when I try to validate the data via the `inputs.Unpack` call, I get an error:

```
 abi: cannot marshal into go array: offset 415 would go over slice boundary (len=8192)
```

My question is, how am I supposed to pack this data correctly so that it may later be unpacked? I would expect the Pack and Unpack methods here to be symmetric but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

OK I think I've figured it out. The Pack/Unpack methods on the Arguments type are asymmetric: Pack will pack all arguments whereas Unpack will filter out indexed arguments first. So the correct way to pack the event data is to call the NonIndexed method first to filter out the indexed fields and not to include indexed fields in the parameter list:

```
    myABI, err := mycontract.MyContractMetaData.GetAbi()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    event := myABI.Events["MyEventName"]
    inputs := event.Inputs
    packedData, err := inputs.NonIndexed().Pack(myEvent.NonIndexedField1, ...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    _, err = inputs.Unpack(packedData)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```